# Android: ViewPager + Fragments: modify fragment view when "onPageScrolled"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Well, I think the title is quite self explanatory. I have a `ViewPager` in my `HomeActivity`, the ViewPager contains 5 fragments at the moment.

When one of the fragments is visible by calling ViewPager's `onPageScrolled` I want to modify some views inside the current displayed fragment according to some conditions in the `HomeActiviy`.

After some research, it seems like I cannot find a good way to communicate in the direction **HomeActivity --> Fragments inside ViewPager**.

I have easily solved the communication in the direction **Fragments in ViewPager --> HomeActivity** using an `Interface`but this trick seems to not be working on the other direction.

I can access each time the current displayed fragment using a method on my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
public Fragment getActiveFragment(int position){
    return myFragmentsList.get(position);
}
```

However, by doing that, I would have to cast each `Fragment` into its class `MyFragment1` `MyFragment2` `MyFragment3`....

Any easy clean way to achieve that?. Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
   mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            if (currentStatus == 1){
            Fragment activeFrag = mPagerAdapter.getActiveFragment(mPager.getCurrentItem());
            //here I would like to modify one of the 5 fragments

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an interface,

```
interface FragmentListenerInterface {
   public void onFragmentSelected();
}
```

Implement this interface in all of your fragments. change the communication between fragment and viewpager. write a method to return fragmentlistenerinterface instead of fragment.

```
public FragmentListenerInterface getActiveFragment(int position){
       return (FragmentListenerInterface) myFragmentsList.get(position);
}
```

After this just say, in your code

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
   mViewPager.getActiveFragment(position).onFragmentSelected(); 
}
```

And implement ***onFragmentSelected()*** in every fragment.